# Excel vba using table from hidden sheet in vba datavalidation

Tags: excel, named-ranges

How to use  table from hidden sheet ?

I get error on

```
With Range("AI5:AI" & LastRow).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=MyTableFromHiddenSheet"
    .IgnoreBlank = True: .InCellDropdown = True: .InputTitle = vbNullString: .ErrorTitle = vbNullString: .InputMessage = vbNullString:          .ErrorMessage = vbNullString: .ShowInput = False: .ShowError = True
End With
```

It required to create namedrange with refernce to Table1 no direct access like in unhided sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are receiving the error due to the sheet being hidden?  The code appears to work properly for me even with a hidden sheet once I remove the undefined variable (in the snippet) `LastRow`.

To name the range (if that's the issue you're having), you can use the following (even on a hidden sheet):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2").Name = "NameForRange"
```

Comment: if i hide a sheet, EXCEL also hide the table reference to this sheet, now i do namedrange to table

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.  The problem you are having does not seem to be with the code you posted.  The code seems to work okay.